# Macro Google Sheet Buscar y Remplazar

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

estoy intentando crear una macro para sustituir un conjunto de palabras por otra. Pero no me funciona :/ pego el código ¿Alguna idea? (no se programar)

```
function FandR(){
  var Prueba
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = sh.getSheetByName("Prueba");
  const f = /Desarrollador de proyectos|Hankkeen rakennuttaja|Proje Firması|Project Developer|Projectontwikkelaar|Projektentwickler|Projektutvecklare|Promotor|Promotore|Prosjektutvikler|יזם/;
  var r = "Project Developer";
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  Logger.log(data.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < data[0].length;i++){
    for (var j = 0; j < data.length;j++){
      if(data[j][i]==f)
      ss.getRange(j+1,i+1).setValue(r);
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia

```
const f = /Desarrollador de proyectos|Hankkeen rakennuttaja|Proje Firması|Project Developer|Projectontwikkelaar|Projektentwickler|Projektutvecklare|Promotor|Promotore|Prosjektutvikler|יזם/;
```

(asignación de una [expresión regular](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) a la variable f)

por

```
const f = ['Desarrollador de proyectos','Hankkeen rakennuttaja','Proje Firması','Project Developer','Projectontwikkelaar','Projektentwickler','Projektutvecklare','Promotor','Promotore','Prosjektutvikler','יזם'];
```

(asignación de un objeto tipo Array con elementos de tipo string)
y

```
data[j][i]==f
```

por

```
f.includes(data[j][i])
```

Para entender lo anterior, deberás aprender, por lo menos, acerca de los tipos de datos, las expresiones de comparación y el método [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) de JavaScript el cual es el lenguaje de programación usado en Google Apps Script, así como también de [Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)